# NDB: how to get child entities that depend on values stored on a parent structured propery

Tags: python, app-engine-ndb

I have the following models:

```py
class Roles(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    type = ndb.StringProperty(choices=['writer', 'editor', 'admin']

class Book(ndb.Model):
    uid = dnb.StringProperty(required=True)
    user = ndb.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True)
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    shared_with = ndb.StructuredProperty(Roles, repeated=True, indexed=True)

class Page(ndb.Model):
    uid = dnb.StringProperty(required=True)
    user = ndb.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    parent_uid = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.key.parent().get().uid) 
    shared_with = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.key.parent().get().shared_with)
```

The structure I am using is:

```
 Book1   Book2  - (parent)
  |        |
  ^        ^
pages    pages  - (child)
```

When a **Book** is created, the **shared_with** is filled with a list of emails/roles.

For example:

```py
Book.uid = user.user_id()
Book.user = user
Book.name =  "learning appengine NDB"
Book.shared_with = [Roles("user_1@domain.tld", "admin"), Roles("user_2@domain.tld", "editor")]
```

When a user creates a **Page**, the `user.user_id()` is stored as uid.

Example when user_2@domain.tld (*role type: editor*) creates a page:

```py
 Page.title = "understanding ComputedProperty"
 Page.uid = user.user_id()
 Page.user = user
```

With this schema, if I want to show to user_2@domain.tld only The pages he has created, I can do a simple query by filtering by uid, with something like:

```
# supposing user_2@domain.tld is logged in
user2_pages = Page.query(Page.uid = user.user_id())
```

But for other users that are listed on the **shared_with** property of the Book,  how could I continue to show their own (pages they created), and all the rest only if they have a `Role`(*admin,editor*).

For example, if I want to allow other users (*admins,editors*); to see a list of last pages created for all the books, how could I perform a query to do so?

What I have been trying so far and not working, is to use a **ComputedProperty**, I can't make it work as expected.

To verify that I get the correct values, I do a query like:

```
query = Pages.query().get()
print query.parent_uid
```

I do get the parent uid, same with the the shared.with values, but for an unknown reason I can't filter with them, when using something like:

```
query = Pages.query(
          Pages.parent_uuid == user.user_id()
        )
# query returns None
```

A probably better and simpler  approach is to show pages per book but I would like to know if it is possible to do it for all the books, so that *admins* and *editors* can just see a list of last pages created in general, instead of going into each book.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your computed property cannot work because it's only updated when Page entity is put. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630991/1756187. Any changes to Book entities have no effect on Page computed properties.

You can try to use Model hooks to maintain Page.shared_with. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks.

I'm wondering though if this is the best approach. If you have the sharing info on the Book level, you can use its index to retrieve the list of book keys. You can do that using keys only query. Then you can retrieve the list of all pages for these parent keys. That way you don't have to add shared_with attribute to Page model at all. The cost of query will be slightly bigger, but the Page entities will be smaller and cheaper to maintain